# What is the depth of this recursive function?

Tags: recursion, depth

What is the depth of the following recursive function?

```
T(n) = r + T(n-r)
```

where `r < n` and if `2r > n` then `r = n-r`,
and the stop condition if `n = r`

Example:

```
n = 24, r  = 9

2r < n, 2*9 < 24, r is fixed (r=9)

T(24) = 9 + T(24-9)= 9 + T(15)

----------

2r > n, 2*9 >15, then r = 15 - 9 = 6

T(15) = 6 + T(15-6)= 6 + T(9)

------------

2r > n, 2*6 > 9, r = 9- 6 = 3

T(9) = 3 + T(9-3) = 3 + T(6)

-----------

2r = n, 2*3 = 6, r is fixed (r=3)

T(6) = 3 + T(6- 3) = 3 + T(3)

------------

Stop condition, r equals n
```

The time complexity is O(n).

This problem can be addressed by recursion trees but this solution is not generic for all values n and r.

I am searching for a formula to find the depth of this recursive equation.

Comment: I think you made mistake in the third part. r = 8 then for T(9) , r = 1 and so on.

Comment: @mmdrezabaqalpour, thanks too much! I fixed this mistake.

Comment: If `r = 1` or `r = n - 1`, then `depth = n`. Isn't that your upper bound?

Comment: @Jeppe, given n and r values, I want to find an equation of the exact depth, not the upper bound. Thanks!

Comment: I write the code to find the pattern of the depth but I couldn't get anything. r = 1 then depth = n and r = n/2 then depth = 2;

Comment: @mmdrezabaqalpour, Thanks! I have tried that too. I appreciate your time and efforts!

Comment: Yea. your welcome. I try whether I could get a proper answer.